# but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:bean'

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

i know this has been asked in so many queries. I am posting as I tried all options and still getting the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cts"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</mvc:bean>
<mvc:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
</mvc:bean>
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"></bean>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.,servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="locale"></property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I am getting that

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:bean'.    spring-servlet.xml  /CATestSlotBooking_Skeleton/WebContent/WEB-INF  line 17 XML Problem

i am using Spring 4.01 release jars

Answer (score 2):

Looks like schema is missing.

Update XML header like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this spring-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cts"></context:component-scan>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    </bean>
    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"></bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.,servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale"></property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

`InternalResourceViewResolver` & `messageSource` are wrongly defined in your xml. There is no such tag as `mvc:bean`. That's why a problem. Should be as follows.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
</bean>
```